# Unary relation in a logical sentence

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I'd appreciate help with this sentence:

Let there be a language L and a structure M, and I need to prove the following sentence is logically false:
$$\varphi :\exists xR(x)\rightarrow \forall yR(y)$$

My problem with this is that I'm having a hard time understanding what an unary relation is. The same example would be much easier (for me) if R was a binary relation.

I'd appreciate some examples for such a relation. Thank you

Comment: Think about the unary relation $O$ on $\mathbb{N}$ of being odd. $O(x)$ is true iff $x=2k-1$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: No problem! Does this answer your question, or do you need more help?

Comment: It helped me a lot, however do you have more examples of unary relations? Also, just to make sure I interpreted your answer correctly:
The sentence is false since it says "There exists an x so that x is odd, so this implies that all y's are odd" ? (More or less)

Comment: Yes, you interpreted it correctly. A unary relation $R$ over a domain $D$ can be viewed as a subset of $D$(just as a $n$-ary relation over $D$ can be viewed as a subset of $D^n$.) For a set $A\subset D$, you have the relation $R_A$ defined by $R_A(x)$ is true iff $x\in A$. The problem with this is there is the empty unary relation $R_\emptyset$ and the total unary relation $R_D$ for which the statement $\varphi$ holds for. $\varphi$ is false for all the other unary relation though.

Comment: @SeanEnglish - Good explanation about unary relations, this helped me after 9 months. Albeit a side note on the question: although the formula in this question is false(mostly), this formula can be easily confused with the formula of the [Drinker Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinker_paradox) which is *valid*.

Comment: Hi everyone. What is the relation and difference between *unary predicates* and *unary relation*?

Comment: @Eric, did you ever find out? Guessing $R_{A}(x)$ is a _predicate_ (i.e. it is a partition on a product space $D^{n}$) whereas $R$ is the subset of $D^{n}$ with "true" elements with respect to $R_{A}$. In closer to computer science terms, I think a _predicate_ is a function of a given type which returns a boolean value (with the function's arity being equal to the order/degree/power of the relation) whereas a _relation_ is a structure containing all of the instances which "satisfy" the predicate.

Comment: Borrowing Go's syntax for type aliasing, variadic functions, and generic types, generally speaking: `type Predicate[T any] func(T...)bool`.

Specifically:
`type UnaryPredicate[T any] func(T) bool`,
`type BinaryPredicate[T any] func(T, T) bool`, and 
`type TernaryPredicate[T any] func(T, T, T) bool`